# chown in scripts

Tags: php, python, chown

Update: turns out the problem is more complicated than I originally thought.  I was simultaneously trying to troubleshoot why my `mkdir` stopped working and it was because I had manually changed permissions of the parent directory to test then switched them back and added a `chmod` to the script which doesn't work since that one is being run by `apache` and not myself.  I'll be posting a new question with the larger problem as I think adding all of this into this one will become confusing.

---

I'm a lab instructor at my university and I've been rewriting the script they provide for uploading assignments because the one they have is old and buggy. Instead of modifying the existing script (written in python) I've been writing it from scratch in php.

I've come across an issue where it seems that chown is not working. The php scripts run under the user `apache`. I'm not sure if that user is 'priveleged' or not but the original script used chown.

Can I assume that therefore `apache` should have the needed authority and that my issue lies elsewhere or is that faulty logic?

---

The server is the university's and there is no way they will let me make any configuration changes.  I do believe that it is CentOS that they're running.  There is no error message i just noticed that I can `chmod` the file and change the permissions but that the `chown` command on the next line seems to have no effect.

`ls -al` on the old scripts show:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mattw labstaff 5067 Sep  1 17:52 File_Upload.cgi
```

Doesn't look like the setuid bit is on.

Stefan mentioned "The user apache most likely doesn't have enough permissions to chown a file/folder it does not own".  The directory I'm attempting to `chown` was just created with a `mkdir` so it should be owned by apache.  Should `chown` work regardless of privilege when  you already own the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache probably doesn't have the privileges to do so. It depends on which environment it's running in. You said apache is running under the user apache, so I'm just going to assume that it's RHEL or a RHEL variant such as Centos.

You would be able to edit the sudoers file (with visudo) and give apache the ability to sudo without a password under a certain directory. Be aware that this isn't recommended if you're very security conscious.

Adding something like

apache        ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/chown 1[1-9][0-9][0-9]\:1[1-9][0-9][0-9] /var/www/[a-zA-Z0-9]*

You may be able to add apache to a different group, or another user to the apache group or something of the sort and chmodding it to 0775 or 0664 instead.

It would be best to post the code that's throwing the error, the error message if any, and which users and groups need access to the files being uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

If the old script is run by the *apache* user but is able to execute `chown` it may have the [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit on to allow it to run with elevated privileges. In that case your assumption would be wrong.

Please post the output of `ls -al /path/to/script` to confirm this. It should show `root` as its owner and a `s` in its mode.

To enable setuid mode for the new script, `chmod u+s`  it. Do note this may have serious security implications. In particular never leave a setuid script or binary writeable.

Answer (score 1):

The user apache most likely doesn't have enough permissions to chown a file/folder it does not own, you can give apache more rights however this could become a security concern.